# mailx how to add attachment

Tags: linux, unix, mailx

How can I add attachment to mailx mail?

```
mail -s "my subject" -a /home/foo/dummy.log me@me.com
```

when using the above I get email and the body test is `/home/git/dummy.log`instead of the actual file

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/104833) use you should use:

echo "MESSAGE BODY" | mailx -s "SUBJECT" -a "FILEPATH" -a "ANOTHERFILE" USER@DOM.TLD

Answer (score 0):

Take care if you are under **HP-UX** system you should use this :
`( cat message_content_file; ux2dos attachment_file.txt | uuencode attachment_file.txt attachment_file.txt ) | mailx -m -s "subject" -r mail@sender mail@recipient`

The attachment file can differ from .txt

Hope it can help !